# SSIS: ispac to dtsx via Linux or programmatically extract file

Tags: java, c#, sql-server, linux, ssis

Is it possible to deploy ispac file to SSIS from the Linux server or extract / convert a file to dtsx format?

If we can't do that from Linux, because only SQL Server engine is available, then is it possible to do that from Java, eventually .Net Core or Python?

If you know how to do that manually, I'll try to write the app for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ispac file is kind of a compressed file that contains individual dtsx files that belong to same project along with project parameters. Try opening it with any application that can read zips.

What I do on windows is that I change the extension from ispac to zip and then simply unzip it and grab the desired dtsx from the folder.